# Mongoose Alias for Virtual Field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to make an alias for a virtual field in mongoose.

Here is the defined schema:

```
let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
});
```

I also defined a virtual field named `fullName` which combines the values of `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function () {
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
});
```

---

The question this, is it possible to have an alias (e.g. `name`) for this virtual field **without having to** create another virtual field with separate setter and getter functions?

Comment: Why not just write the one `function()` and then supply "that" as the content for the getter? Because it's just a standard JavaScript function after-all.